# Does supply a sample that could run it successfully is so difficult or just spring is so difficult to use naturally?

Tags: spring-boot

I git cloned `spring-boot` and wanted to start `spring-boot-sample-web-ui`, after importing it to intellij idea and run `SampleWebUiApplication`, first I met this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
```

Then added this dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Run it again have another error again

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.http.client.support.BasicAuthorizationInterceptor
```

Does supply a sample that could start it successfully is so difficult or just spring is so difficult to use naturally?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach if you are new to Spring / Spring Boot is to look at the [Getting Started guides](https://spring.io/guides). I haven't had an issue yet with one of those and having them work properly. Based on the sample you listed I am guessing the [Serving Web Content with Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) would be a good one to look at.

I did try the spring-boot-sample-web-ui project in my local environment using Eclipse. I didn't run into any issues with it so it looks like it might be an issue with the way you imported / loaded the project in IntelliJ.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved it by change parent in pom

```
        <parent>
-               <!-- Your own application should inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
-               <artifactId>spring-boot-samples</artifactId>
-               <version>1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
+               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
+               <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>
```

Comment: No idea where you got this example, but I don't think any example is meant to be used with a snapshot build version.